# Remove HTML, HEAD and BODY Tags for fetching SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to fetch a SVG image from a link. When fetching a svg image from https://www.coingecko.com/coins/976/sparkline it works perfectly, the svg image gets dsplayed. When I'm trying to fetch it from https://www.coinparticle.com/sparkline/bitcoin it doesn't display.

I think this has something to do with certain tags used in the HTML code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

How can I adjust the code on coinparticle to fetch the svg image (I have access to the coinparticle server)?

```html
1
<img class="1" src="https://www.coingecko.com/coins/7598/sparkline">

2
<img class="2" src="https://www.coinparticle.com/sparkline/bitcoin">
```

Code on coinparticle:

```
<html></html>

<script>

  const height = 50; //the number of pixels high the chart is to be
  const points = [[1631264425426,46187.88927989531],[1631268120084,46346.477413458255],[1631271810755,46460.52411265284],[1631275266134,46472.58450929567]]

  const len = points.length;
  let minx = points[0][0]
  let maxx = points[0][0];
  let miny = points[0][1];
  let maxy = points[0][1];

  points.forEach( (point) => {
    minx = (point[0] < minx) ? point[0] : minx;
    maxx = (point[0] > maxx) ? point[0] : maxx;
    miny = (point[1] < miny) ? point[1] : miny;
    maxy = (point[1] > maxy) ? point[1] : maxy;
  } );

  function setup() {
    const width = 135;
    let svg = '<svg width="' + width +  '" height="' + (height+4) + '" viewBox="0 0 135 54"' + '"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' + '"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"' + '><polyline points="';

    points.forEach( (point) => {
      svg = svg + ((point[0] - minx) / (maxx - minx)) * width + ',' + (height - ((point[1] - miny) / (maxy - miny)) * height + 2) + ' ';
    });
    svg = svg + '" stroke-linejoin="round" style="fill: transparent; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" /></svg>';

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', svg)

  }
  setup();

</script>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi Robbert I already tried that and it seems to not be working. Do you think it has something to do with the tags?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have added a working prototype. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: An image can't run script so when you write `<img class="2" src="https://www.coinparticle.com/sparkline/bitcoin">` no script within `https://www.coinparticle.com/sparkline/bitcoin` will run

Comment: @RobertLongson m okay. So how can I solve this? I want to create a svg image from the dataset and fetch that image. How can I go about this? (I use nodejs as backend)

Comment: Don't use an img tag. Both iframe and object tags allow their contents to run script.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your code on coinparticle, you could instead create a small `iframe` to load the content.

```html
1
<img class="1" src="https://www.coingecko.com/coins/7598/sparkline">

2
<iframe src="https://www.coinparticle.com/sparkline/bitcoin" width="135" height="54" scrolling="no" style="border:0;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Perfect! If i want to change the code how should I do it? And what are the main drawbacks of using an iframe instead of img, is it loading time?